# Calculating the work done by a particle experiencing a force in polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces, work

[image]

Above is the source of uncertainty I have in understanding the motion of this particular particle. I'm consider (a) here, and here is my thinking:

- The particle's motion is hard for me to understand. Radially, it seems to jerk, as the force increases with radius. Perpendicular to $\hat r$, it seems to have a force on it depending on its position. At $\theta = \pi / 2$, for instance, it will have no $\hat \theta$ directed force on it, but, how then does it feel a force in the direction of $\hat \theta$ afterwards? Does it get to $\pi / 2$ and stay there?
- Regardless of how it moves, calculating the work done can be done by considering the dot product of the force and some arbitrary position vector $\vec {dr}$. Now, since in polar $\vec r$ need only be expressed using $\hat r$ in the equation $\vec r = r\ \hat r$, my instinct would be to represent $\vec {dr}$ as $\vec {dr} = dr\hat r$. However, my other idea is to use $\vec {dr} = dr\hat r + d\theta \hat \theta$. This would make the dot product more straightforward as well, as I can resolve work in $\hat \theta$ but I feel like that would imply $\vec r = r\hat r + \theta \hat \theta$ which doesn't make sense to me, as I've never seen a position vector in polar described that way.

To calculate the work done in moving from $(0,0)$ to $(1,\pi/4)$, there will be work contributions in $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$. So:

$$W = \int_0^1 a\ r\  dr + \int_0^{\pi/4}a\cos\theta \ d\theta$$

Regardless of path, moving from $(0,0$ to $(1,\pi/4)$ should involve this work contribution. For (a), I interpret "the path $\theta = \pi/4$ " as $r$ extending from $0$ to $\infty$ at angle $\pi/4$ from the origin, as $r$ is unbounded with $\theta = \pi/4$. Due to this, $\theta$ is fixed in this path, so we only concern ourselves with this integral. This causes us to have our answer as $a/2$. However, if this is indeed correct, the questions highlighted in my bullet points still have no good answer from me, so addressing them would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the case (a) here. In this case, the angle stays at $\frac{\pi}{4}$, since at $(0,0)$, the angle is not defined. Now,

- A radius dependent force is natural. It does jerk radially but that is okay, since that happens continuously. The force due to a spring is of this nature, for instance.
- The position vector is indeed $\vec{r}=r\hat{r}$, but $\hat{r}$ is not fixed in polar coordinates, but depends on where you are, i.e., $\hat{r}=\hat{r}(r,\theta)$. Indeed, what you get is,
  $$d\vec{r}=\hat{r}\,dr+\hat{\theta}\,(r\,d\theta)$$
  You can essentially look into any book dealing with curvilinear coordinate systems, and they would give you the expression for the infinitesimal displacement vector $d\vec{r}$.

Comment: Ah yes, this is the velocity equation just without the $dt$ terms.

Comment: Absolutely. Also, you can figure this out by looking at a small displacement and how changes in $r$ and $\theta$ contribute to that.

Comment: I can definitely see that, but what makes me a bit confused is how $\vec r = r \hat r $ suffices for a position vector equation but doesn't for a change in position. Like, I know $\hat r$ varies with $\theta$ but how does it then describe everything we need for position, but we now need $\hat r$ AND $\hat \theta$ for $dr$? The equations themselves make intuitive sense to me, but I can't answer that question very well regardless.

Comment: When you are writing $\vec{r}=r\hat{r}$, you are basically expressing the position vector with respect to the origin, and $\hat{r}$ takes care of the angle, while for $d\vec{r}$, you have to specify changes in both.